# GWT Images Set Size

Tags: gwt

I have some images I am swapping out in a image widget by setUrl.The problem is I start with smaller images then when I load a larger image into the image widget it remains the same size as the smaller image.

Is there any way I can make the widget auto adjust it's width and height to the image I am loading into it.

Right now I am keeping the dimesions in an array and adjusting size accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Actually using `setUrl(String)` does also work for me. Can you provide some code?

Comment: OK it worked.I had set a size on the image widget.Once I removed the size attributes it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the new images by calling [`setResource(ImageResource)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#setResource%28com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource%29)? This works for me.

Comment: I have my images in an array as strings i.e "image1.png".That above gives an error.Do I need to use an image Bundle or something?

Comment: Exactly. Have a look at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html for more information on that topic.